# How to enter folder path into New Custom Field Default Value?

Tags: custom-field

I am trying to make a custom text field and set the default value for it to a folder path on the C drive.  However it is giving me "Error: Invalid Data.", I assume this is due to the slashes in the folder path, how do I escape them?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With another `\`:

```
("C:\\")
```

This is similar to how you'd do it in Apex or many other programming languages.